# Using lib compiled in masm in c++

Tags: c++, assembly, static-libraries, masm32

im trying to make a lib in masm32 (using radasm) for use in other projects...

the libs source code :

```
.386
.MODEL flat,stdcall
option casemap:none
.code
start:
PUBLIC HookProc
HookProc proc addy:DWORD
```

and for use in msvc :

```
extern "C" void* HookProc(void* ptr);
#pragma comment(lib, "TestHook.lib")
```

however this produces an error :

> Win32Project1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _HookProc referenced in function _wmain

but i see in the lib there is

```
!<arch>
/               1368690603              0       20        `
®_HookProc@4/               1368690603              0       26        `
```

Why cant msvc see this proc in the lib ?? ;/ does this have something to do with the `@4` ?

Edit : changed to `.MODEL flat, c` that got rid of @4 , but still _HookProc uresolved......

Comment: Can you show the assmebly file? Not neccessarily the whole function, just the declarations would suffice. I provided a small sample which I tested and works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPP:

```
extern "C" int GetValue(void);

int main(int argc, char*arg[])
{
    char *p = "test";
    int v = GetValue();

    return 0;
}
```

ASM:

```
.486
.model flat, C
option casemap :none

.code

GetValue PROC
    mov eax, 1234
    ret
GetValue ENDP

END
```

Comment: actually it works with `.model flat, c` so my fail was calling conventions.

Comment: Well it was a nice exercise for me to get back into this assembly stuff. I had to google for examples because I ran into the same problem. :)